# Why does Live Test in Google Search Console return content that is not viewable in the browser?

Tags: seo, google-search, google-search-console

According to Google Search Console Live Test on https://www.energycouncil.com.au/ returns text that does not exist on the viewable website.

[image]

[image]

Why is completely different source returned when using the Google Search Console with a Live Test?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because, from the tag: SEO questions are off-topic. Only programming-related SEO questions are acceptable on Stack Overflow. Non-programming SEO questions should be asked on Webmasters.SE at https://webmasters.stackexchange.com. If someone has directed you here to read this warning, go back and delete your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked it out.

Code had been injected into a source code file that redirects the site if it is a website indexer. Ingeniously, this code did not do anything for over a year so I didn't see the issue as no files appeared to be recently modified.

To find the issue, download the live site and search it for "redirect"